Estimate of supremum of derivative by supremum of function and second derivative
Edit: The original question was wrong. The term $||f'||_\infty$ appeared on the LHS without the square.
For a homework question I have to solve the following problem:
Let $f \in C^2([0,1])$. The task is to show that there exists $M>0$ (independent of $f$) such that
$$||f'||^2_\infty \le M ||f||_\infty (||f||_\infty + ||f''||_\infty)$$
where $||f||_\infty$ denotes the supremum norm on the interval $[0,1]$.
Here's what I tried so far:
I know that there is a statement (e.g. in Rudin's analysis book) that says $||f'||_\infty^2 \le 4 ||f||_\infty ||f''||_\infty$, which is normally formulated for functions on $\mathbb R$ and its proof would need to be modified for functions on an interval because it is not true for linear functions (which in the case of functions on $\mathbb R$ are excluded anyway by the assumption that all three suprema are finite).
However, nothing I have tried so far worked.$.
I tried to use the mean value theorem for $f$ or the fundamental theorem of calculus for either $f$ or $f'$, but somehow I never ended up with an estimate good enough. Any help would be appreciated.

The scaling doesn’t seem to work out; if you replace $f$ by $cf$ then your inequality becomes $|f’|\infty \leq cM |f|\infty(|f|\infty + |f’’|\infty)$, so if $f$ is nonconstant, sending $c$ to zero yields a contradiction.

@kieransquared you are right. This can not be true in the given form. I will check if I copied the assignment correctly

@kieransquared I rechecked and there was a mistake in the question. It was supposed to be a square on the left hand side. Now the scaling is the same on both sides of the equation.
